# Flutter - Passing data between stateful widget in a socket connection

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and I am woking on sockets which keeps streaming data which I need to update on a appbar. So I have to stateful widgets

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
TickerAppBar appBar = TickerAppBar();
//Some declarations

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    connectionSetup();
  }


connectionSetup() async {
    this.socket.connect(connectionString);
    this.socket.sendSubscription(subscriptionString);
    await processData();
}

Future<Null> processData() async{
    subscription = socket.streamController.stream.listen(
        (data) {
         appBar.setStreamData(data); //Passing data into appbar widget
         //rest of the code of current widget
         }
     );
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: appBar,
        //rest of the code
    )
}

}

class TickerAppBar extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget  {
String streamData;
_TickerAppBarState child = _TickerAppBarState();

setStreamData(data){
    this.streamData = data;
    child.processData(); //To invoke the function every time the data is passed 
  }
}

class _TickerAppBarState extends State<TickerAppBar>{

Future<String> processData() async{
//Cannot set state here since its a constructor and the widget is not mounted.
}

}
```

So how I can set the data every time the data is passed into tickerappbar? so that my custom appbar displays new data which comes in every second.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you follow the BLoC pattern, in which you can define your streams at one place and subscribe to the said stream from any widget, once you have the data ready, you can write to the stream and it will be shared on all the subscribed widgets.